# Check details of SMS in RingCentral

Tags: ringcentral

I am using Python SDK for sending SMS via programing. I will be integrating the application with a web application. SMS is working fine with Python SDK.
Is there any way to check the history of SMS that I have send using the Python SDK?
How can be done with an API where I get all the details of my SMS history.
So far I can check the details from RingCentral online account and get the details. But I want to get it via API. What is the option on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Log is one of the the way to check the history

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference

You can find the endpoints to check sms history in the **Call Log** and "Messages" sections.

Alternately you can get the history in RingCentral App's Settings section in logs.